# AngularJS: How can I assign values to main page from templates and show them?

Tags: angularjs

In my mine file I have the div with ng-view and it is loaded with the some template. Inside the temp`late I have a button which will change the value.

after to click the button, I am trying to show the value in the index but I recieving a null value.

In index.html I could have something like:

```
<html>
    ...
    <body ng-app="productsApp" ng-Controller="mycontroller">
      <div ng-view></div>

      {{value}}
    </body>
</html>
```

In my controller I have something like

```
angular.module('productsApp').controller('ProductController', 
    ['$scope', 'dataService', function ($scope, dataService) {

    $scope.value;

    $scope.button = function () {
        $scope.value=  "123";
    };
}]);
```

The template could be something like:

```
<button ng-click="button">CHANGE</button>
```

How can I assign values to main page from templates and show them?

Comment: Several bugs in your code. Some Hints: ng-click doesn't call a method. What is `$.scope.value` - typo?. What is the name of your controller in JavaScript and which one are you refering to in your HTML?

Comment: as I comented the name is ProductController, take a lookin controller I mentioned it in the question, sorry to set . after $. just typing fast. Could you see the type of variable inside the controller I set "123" then it is a string. I is an example I think it is enough information... then ... not serveral errors, only one and sorry for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to beware which controller you set, the names have to match. Also beware of typos, even when typing fast ;). Also look into the function call. You forgot to use () at the end. And naming things a little bit better would be recommended to (I don't say my namings are the best, but calling a function button is not very readable).

#### HTML

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Value {{value}}!</p>
    <button ng-click="btnPressed()">Change</button>
  </body>
```

#### JS

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.value = "456";

  $scope.btnPressed = function() {
    $scope.value = 123;
  }
});
```

The controllers name in this example is MainCtrl. You need to refer the correct name as well in your HTML (you mix mycontroller and ProductController).

#### Working Plnkr

http://plnkr.co/edit/tpl:8rFfZljYNl3z1A4LKSL2

Answer (score 0):

You have defined `$scope.button` in `ProductController` which set `$scope.value`.

But this `$scope.value` is come under scope of `ProductController` and not available under scope of `mycontroller` which parent scope.Thats why you getting null value.

Define `$scope.value` and `$scope.button` in `mycontroller`.

Or better  way is define this functionality in some `factory` and access it wherever needed.

Or define that function and variable in `$rootScope` like

```
 $rootScope.value;
```

but it make this global.

or define like this

```
 $scope.$parent.value;
```